# Using ANTLR4 lexing for Code Completion in Netbeans Platform

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer, netbeans-platform

I am using ANTLR4 to parse code in my Netbeans Platform application. I have successfully implemented syntax highlighting using ANTLR4 and Netbeans mechanisms.

I have also implemented a simple code completion for two of my tokens. At the moment I am using a simple implementation from a tutorial, which searches for a whitespace and starts the completion process from there. This works, but it deems the user to prefix a whitespace before starting code completion.

My question: is it possible or even contemplated using ANTLR's lexer to determine which tokens are currently read from the input to determine the correct completion item?

I would appreciate every pointer in the right direction to improve this behaviour.

Comment: I think that ANTLR is more suitable for compilers but not for IDE. In IDE 99% of the time the code is broken so that it requires strong error handling which I don't think can be easily achieved by ANTLR. A framework such as Microsoft's Roslyn might be good enough, but not sure if anything similar exists for Java.

Comment: Well, the parsing works beautifuly as it is right now. I only want to use the generated parser at the code completion stage to determine which tokens are currently viable and deliver the appropriate completions depending on this.

Answer (score 1):

not really an answer, but I do not have enough reputation points to post comments.

> is it possible or even contemplated using ANTLR's lexer to determine which tokens are currently read from the input to determine the correct completion item?

Have a look here: http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2008-November/031576.html
and here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/antlr-discussion/DbJ-2qBmNk0
Bear in mind that first post was written in 2008 and current antlr v4 is very different from the one available at the time, which is why Sam’s opinion on this topic appear to have evolved.

My personal experience - most of what you are asking is probably doable with antlr, but you would have to know antlr **very** well. A more straightforward option is to use antlr to gather information about the context and use your own heuristics to decide what needs to be shown in this context.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. Using ANTLR to gather information about the current context upon executing code completion sounds exactly like what I am trying to achieve. I simply want to determine if a certain ist currently viable and I can add the options for this token to the code completion. I will have a look at your links tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ANTLRv3 grammar https://sourceware.org/git/?p=frysk.git;a=blob_plain;f=frysk-core/frysk/expr/CExpr.g;hb=HEAD implements context sensitive completion of C expressions (no macros).

For instance, if fed the string:

```
a_struct->a<tab>
```

it would just lists the fields of "a_struct" starting with "a" (tab could, technically be any character or marker).

The technique it used was to:

- modify a C grammar to recognize both IDENT and IDENT_TAB tokens
- for IDENT_TAB capture the partial expression AST and "TOKEN_TAB" and throw them back to 'main' (there are hacks to help capture the AST)
- 'main' then performs a type-eval on the partial expression (compute the expression's type not value) and use that to expand TOKEN_TAB

the same technique, while not exactly ideal, can certainly be used in ANTLRv4.